# ArrayList search in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I was wondering how I can search an array list with an argument given by program user. List contains information from txt file that is being created when user enters info.
So it goes like this:

IME: kontakt1ime| PREZIME: kontakt1prezime| BROJ: kontakt1broj| E-MAIL: kontakt1mail

IME: kontakt2ime| PREZIME: kontakt2prezime| BROJ: kontakt2broj| E-MAIL: kontakt2mail

IME: kontakt3ime| PREZIME: kontakt3prezime| BROJ: kontakt3broj| E-MAIL: kontakt3mail

This it the text that is being inserted in list when a method is called and now when user enters name/number/mail, I need to print all info of that contact.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen [Tokenizers](https://crunchify.com/java-stringtokenizer-and-string-split-example/)?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  You could use a regex to extract information from the four fields.  What do you actually need to print?

Comment: Well I did try something with hasNext() but I'm new to Java so I don't actualy have an idea of what else to do.
Well for example if user should type kontakt1mail, program should print 
IME: kontakt1ime| PREZIME: kontakt1prezime| BROJ: kontakt1broj| E-MAIL: kontakt1mail, all info of contact1

Comment: Would it be okay if instead of an `ArrayList`, you just used an `String` array? This would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I interpreted your question correctly, but I think this is what you wanted. This program accepts a username and shows that users contact info. The contact info is taken from a txt file(I called mine `Contacts.txt`). Here is the program, along with the file.

Program:

```
public class Experiments {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("/Users/Username/Location/Contacts.txt"); //change to location of your file
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

        String[][] users = {reader.nextLine().split(" - "), reader.nextLine().split(" - "), reader.nextLine().split(" - ")};
        boolean validUserName = false;
        while (!validUserName) { 
            System.out.println("Enter your User name.");
            String userName = input.next();
            for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < users[i].length; j++){
                    if (users[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(userName)){
                        System.out.println("INFO FOR: " + users[i][0]);
                        System.out.println("IME: " + users[i][1]);
                        System.out.println("PREZIME: " + users[i][2]);
                        System.out.println("BROJ: " + users[i][3]);
                        System.out.println("EMAIL: " + users[i][4]);
                        validUserName = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!validUserName){
                System.out.println("Invalid User name. Please try again.");
            }
        }
        input.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

And here is the file(`Contacts.txt`). This file can hold infinite usernames as long as they follow the same format

```
kontakt1 - kontakt1ime - kontakt1prezime - kontakt1broj - kontakt1mail
kontakt2 - kontakt2ime - kontakt2prezime - kontakt2broj - kontakt2mail
kontakt3 - kontakt3ime - kontakt3prezime - kontakt3broj - kontakt3mail
```

This does not use an `ArrayList`, but I thought it wasn't necessary that you had one.

Comment: Yeah, this works, but user should be able to enter infinite number of contatcs, not only 3.
So how should it be done?

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok Let me think about that, then fix my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok I fixed my program, and it works. It can now hold infinite values, as long as they follow the format(username - ime - prezime - broj - mail)

Comment: Can you post a code or is it a few lines that need to be changed?

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok I edited my post, and the new code is correct. I only changed a few lines, so it looks very similar. Try reloading the page to update it.

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok If this answer is helpful, please upvote it so future visitors can see. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

- Create a class, call it `User` or something of that nature.
- Inside of this class, add your fields: `ime`, `prezime`, `broj`, and `email`.
- Define a list: `List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();`
- Add your users to this list. If you set up a constructor in your `User` class, you could add each user like this: `users.add(new User("kontakt1ime", "kontakt1prezime", "kontakt1broj", "kontakt1mail"));`

That's how you get your ArrayList, I'm assuming you've gotten this far, but I like to be thorough. To actually answer your question, you'd look through each `User` in the ArrayList, and check for the field. Let's say, get the `User` object for the user with the email `kontakt1mail`:

```
String emailToLookFor = "kontakt1mail";
for(User user : users) {
    if(user.email.equals(emailToLookFor) {
        System.out.println("User: " + user);
    }
}
```

Edit: To address exactly what you wanted, use this instead of your `System.out.println();`

```
System.out.println("User IME: " + user.ime + ". PREZIME: " + user.prezime + ". BROJ: " + user.broj + ". EMAIL: " + user.email);
```

Comment: Yes, this would work, but I don't know how to insert the info of contacts from txt file into the users list you made because it's all strings.
When the program stops, all info is stored in the txt file and when it starts again, if any method is called for just reading the info, it's being added to other string type list with wich this above can't be done.

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok OK, so you need it to be loaded into the `ArrayList` from the `TXT` file?

Comment: Have you gotten that part figured out? It's pretty simple, and I could post code to make that happen. It's only like five(ish) lines.

Comment: I know how to do that, but the code above is imposible to applay on List<String> and it is the only type that is comatibile with txt files.
When I make List<User> that I could work after, it reports error when it needs to read the info from the file.

Comment: Oh, so you store your user information in an ArrayList of Strings. I do recommend you switch to objects, it makes finding values out of them easier, although reading is a little more difficult. Here's the code you'd use if you wanted to read from an example file into the format I showed: EDIT: I'll post a link, comments are strange. Sit tight.

Comment: Here's a link to a piece of code that loads a txt file in this format: `kontakt1ime|kontakt1prezime|kontakt1broj|kontakt1email` It's a little bit of a different format, but I think it could be easily migrated to. Here's the reading code: https://paste.ee/p/DMdJd

Comment: So here is the code that I came up with combining your two codes, and still when I call this method, nothing happens.
Can you see where I made a mistake?
https://paste.ee/p/oGPpV

Comment: Does it ask you to supply your information? If so, try adding `System.out.println("Test Message");` somewhere inside of the `while` loop that goes through the lines in the file. If you don't see it in the console, we have established it's something wrong there.

Comment: Also, completely unrelated, but is this language Croatian?

Comment: It's Serbian, but Croatian and Serbian are very similar languages :D